# Wordpress Change Front page displays settings conditionally when user is online

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Created two pages -> Feeds and Blog

1. If the **user is online** then

   **Front Page displays** settings should point to **A static page** where **Front page** should be "Feeds" and **Posts page** should be "Blog".
2. When the **user is offline** then

   **Front page displays** settings should point to **Your latest posts**, default.

**For that particular users only.**

Comment: someone who can answer this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check if user is logged in:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

And this function to redirect to specific page for each user
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/